# unable to find links in laravel for pagination

Tags: laravel-5, pagination, guzzle

i get a json response like this  note i am using GuzzleHttp to call my API

```
$response =  $response->getBody()->getContents();
$output = (json_decode($response));
dd(output)
```

```
{#232 ▼
  +"current_page": 1
  +"data": array:2 [▼
    0 => {#230 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"test_col": "Test one"
    }
    1 => {#237 ▼
      +"id": 3
      +"test_col": "Test three"
    }
  ]
  +"first_page_url": "http://api/api/test?page=1"
  +"from": 1
  +"last_page": 8
  +"last_page_url": "http://api/api/test?page=8"
  +"next_page_url": "http://api/api/test?page=2"
  +"path": "http://api/api/test"
  +"per_page": 2
  +"prev_page_url": null
  +"to": 2
  +"total": 15
}
```

and now when i go to my front end and do this

```
 {{$outputs->links()}}
```

to get the pagination links it shows me an error

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Call to undefined method stdClass::links()

and on my API side i am doing this

```
      $results = DB::table('test_table')->paginate(2);
        return ($results);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object from the response ($output) can not have any methods. The response already has links (first_page_url, last_page_url, next_page_url). If you need to HTML rendered links then you can try to create instance of [LengthAwarePaginator](https://github.com/illuminate/pagination/blob/master/LengthAwarePaginator.php#L15)

```
$pagination = new LengthAwarePaginator($outputs->data, $outputs->total, $outputs->per_page, $outputs->current_page);
echo $pagination->links();
```

(not tested)

Comment: this is a great solution m almost there 
so when i click the pagination like for example when i click page 2.
it goes back to my index page `http://front.end/?page=2`

Comment: @BenjaminHutchinson You can specify base URL in the fifth parameter of LengthAwarePaginator constructor.
new LengthAwarePaginator($outputs->data, $outputs->total, $outputs->per_page, $outputs->current_page, ['path' => 'http://api/api/test']);